# The Novikov field is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, symplectic-geometry

I have a questions on why the "Novikov field" defined in below is indeed a field:

[image]

Specifically, why every element $\sum_{g\in \Gamma}a_gT^g$ has an inverse? If

$$T^0=\sum_{g\in \Gamma}a_gT^g * \sum_{h\in \Gamma}b_hT^h:=\sum_{l\in \Gamma}(\sum_{g\in \Gamma}a_gb_{l-g})T^l$$

Basically, this means we need to solve the systems:
$\sum_{g\in \Gamma}a_gb_{l-g}=\delta_{0l}$, where $0$ is the additive identity in $\Gamma$. I don't know how to solve this for $b_h$'s.

Although this has a background in symplectic geometry, I hope the solution could be purely algebraic since the definition of this "field" is.

[Source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1502.07928.pdf#page=12#)

Comment: What book is this from?

Comment: @Ryan This is from a paper, please click "Source"

Comment: Oh sorry, didn’t see that. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}\subset \mathbb{R}$, this is the ring of formal Laurent series, and is a field for basically the same reason. Any nonzero formal Laurent series $g(T)$ can be expressed in the form $T^{-n}f(T)$ for $f$ a formal power series in $T$ with $f(0)\neq 0$. Since formal power series are a local ring with maximal ideal $(T)$, we have that $f(T)$ is invertible, and thus the inverse is $T^nf(T)^{-1}$.

So see that any formal power series $f(T)$ with coefficients in $R$ is invertible iff $f(0)\in R^*$, write out the multiplication formula and use induction.

The case of general $\Gamma$ will proceed similarly, since the "support" of a power series always has finitely many elements contained in the ray $(-\infty,a]$, one may perform a similar inductive argument to show that inverses exist.
EDIT- This is a bit trickier that I originally thought.

First multiply by $T^g$ for some $g\in \Gamma$ to get the support of $T^g f(T)$ positive, where we have support of a series being the set of $h\in\Gamma$ with $a_h\neq 0$.

Since $T^g$ is invertible, with inverse $T^{-g}$, we may assume that our power series $f(T)$ has positive support, and multiplying by an element of our field, we may assume that $a_0=1$.(Note that this isn't actually needed, just makes it a bit easier with signs/coefficients).

Then the equation $f(T)*g(T)=1=T^0$ gives a bunch of equations which we will want to set to $0$. The problem is that we don't know a priori what the support of $T$ should be, or if its possible to pick some support with coefficients which allows this. This is definitely trickier than the $\Gamma=\mathbb{Z}$ case.

We can instead construct an inverse inductively by a different method. Let $$f(T)=f_1(T)=1+a_{g_{1,1}}T^{g_{1,1}}+a_{g_{1,2}}T^{g_{1,2}}+...$$
Now let $f_2(T)=(1-(a_{g_{1,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{1,1}})f_1(T)$

Inductively, construct $f_n(T)=(1-(a_{g_{n-1,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{n-1,1}})f_{n-1}(T)$

Where $f_{n-1}(T)=1+a_{g_{n-1,1}}T^{g_{n-1,1}}+...$

We claim first that the sequence $g_{n,1}$ is discrete.

For this, note that if $$f_{n-1}(T)=1+a_{g_{n-1,1}}T^{g_{n-1,1}}+a_{g_{n-1,2}}T^{g_{n-1,2}}...$$

Then smallest coefficient of $f_n(T)$ will either be $T^{2g_{n-1,1}}$ or $T^{g_{n-1,2}}$, and if we had an accumulation point of the $\{g_{n,1}\}$, then this first case couldn't occur, which means that one our our $f_i(T)$ didn't have discrete support, but we know all of them do since the novikov field is a ring.

Then the desired inverse of $f(T)$ is given by $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-(a_{g_{i,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{i,1}})$. This product is well defined by the discreteness of the sequence $\{g_{i,1}\}$, and by construction, there is nothing except $T^0$ in the support of $f(T)\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-(a_{g_{i,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{i,1}})$, so this is a multiplicative inverse.

Comment: $f(T)\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-(a_{g_{i,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{i,1}})=(1+a_{g_{1,1}}T^{g_{1,1}}+a_{g_{1,2}}T^{g_{1,2}}+... )\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-(a_{g_{i,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{i,1}})                         =T^0$ is not very obvious to me... Are you sure that they cancel out easily from comstruction? Is there any relation between $g_{i,j}$ and $g_{j,i}$?

Comment: The indexing might be obscuring whats going on somewhat, we are multiplying our power series by something to increase its smallest nonzero coefficient. We do this process “infinitely many” times to get the desired inverse, combining all these steps. Then its just justifying why this infinite product is well defined. Maybe a good way to see this in action is to build the inverse of $1-x$ in power series, you get $\prod_i(1+x^{2^i}$, which is the inverse $1+x+x^2+..$ written as a product.

Comment: "Then smallest coefficient of $f_n(T)$ will either be $T^{2g_{n-1,1}}$ or $T^{g_{n-1,2}}$, and if we had an accumulation point of the $\{g_{n,1}\}$, then this first case couldn't occur", Could you explain why the first case won't occur if there is an accumulation point?

Comment: and how is the well-definedness of $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{\infty}(1-(a_{g_{i,1}})^{-1}T^{g_{i,1}})$ guaranteed by the discreteness of $\{g_{i,1}\}$?

Comment: Any coefficient is determined by the terms which are strictly less, and by discreteness there are finitely many of these, so the coefficient of any $T^g$ is a finite sum. We also can’t have a failure of discreteness in the product as the $g_{i,1}$ are discrete.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Gamma_0:= \Gamma\cap \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$ be the non-negative subgroup of $\Gamma$. Then $\Lambda$ is the localisation of the ring
$$\Lambda_0 := \big\{\sum_{g\in\Gamma_0 }a_gT^g:a_g\in \mathcal{K} \big\}  $$
at the unique maximal idea of $\Lambda_0$. Since $\mathcal{K}$ is a field the ring $\Lambda_0$ is an integral domain. And hence the localisation is a field.